# How to include Angular Material Design in an Android App

Tags: android, angularjs

I was wondering if it was possible to include AngularJS to design certain elements of my Android App and how one could go about doing so. More specifically, how could I apply this angular api: https://material.angularjs.org/#/material.components.radioButton/directive/materialRadioGroup to a radio group in my android app.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but I wouldn't recommend it for an app yet. If your making a hybrid app I'd recomend taking a look at [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) they basicly intend to fix all the headaches people have with cordova. Their design isn't exactly material but it looks decent and they have plans to switch to material design once angular-material is ready. In fact they are the ones working on angular material.

Comment: Awesome. I'll keep an eye out for updates from ionic. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @epelc until now angular material is not ready yet to them :P